# Eclipse Launcher depends on unattached shared memory segment for restart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, shared-memory, equinox

Investigating why eclipse (running on Linux) sometimes exits rather than restarting as expected, I discovered that a legacy app running on my system was causing the problem. When the app cleans up, it removes any shared memory segment belonging to the current user for which nattach is 0. I discovered that this was the cause of the problem by running strace on the eclipse launcher and seeing a method call with an invalid shared memory address during attempted restart.

We're going to fix the legacy app to do a better job in deciding which shared memory segments to remove, but current installations of the app will continue to break eclipse restart behavior. I don't understand why the memory segment which eclipse is depending on to get the exit code of the JVM is not attached. Is that expected behavior, or a bug? Is there any way to make an existing eclipse installation behave differently so that nattach is not zero for shared memory segments created by the launcher?

Comment: I would suggest you file a bug on Eclipse [bugzilla](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) with as much detail as possible. It is very unlikely that anyone outside of the development team can answer this.

Answer (score 1):

I opened [this eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492618) on the issue.